# TFS Import Work Items

Tags: tfs

I am needing to import a large list of work items with history into TFS (will be upgrading to 2015 soon) from an in house built bug tracking solution.  I know of the excel add-in, but how can I import multiple history items for each work item?  Would writing a program using hte TFS API be a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to import work item with history. This can't be achieved through Excel Add-in. You may have to use TFS API.

Follow below steps:

- Get the Work Item Details Programmatically using TFS API
- Get the Work Item Revision ‘History’ Programmatically using TFS API

Detail ways and API please refer this blog: [TFS SDK: Work Item History Visualizer using TFS API](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/08/21/tfs-sdk-work-item-history-visualizer-using-tfs-api.aspx)